# Getting Rolling Sum per Group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Product_ID    Quantity    Year    Quarter   
  1             100       2021      1          
  1             100       2021      2         
  1              50       2021      3          
  1             100       2021      4          
  1             100       2022      1         
  2             100       2021      1          
  2             100       2021      2          
  3             100       2021      1          
  3             100       2021      2
```

I would like to get the Sum of the last three months (excluding the current month), per Product_ID.

Therefore I tried this:

```
df['Qty_Sum_3qrts'] = (df.groupby('Product_ID'['Quantity'].shift(1,fill_value=0)
                         .rolling(3).sum().reset_index(0,drop=True)
                       )

# Shifting 1, because I want to exclude the current row. 
# Rolling 3, because I want to have the 3 'rows' before 
# Grouping by, because I want to have the calculation PER product
```

My code is failing, because it does not only calculate it per product, but it will give me also numbers for other products (let's say Product 2, quarter 1: gives me the 3 rows from product 1).

My proposed outcome:

```
Product_ID    Quantity    Year    Quarter   Qty_Sum_3qrts
  1             100       2021      1          0 # because we dont historical data for this id
  1             100       2021      2          100 # sum of last month of this product 
  1              50       2021      3          200 # sum of last 2 months of this product
  1             100       2021      4          250 # sum of last 3 months of this product
  1             100       2022      1          250 # sum of last 3 months of this product
  2             100       2021      1          0  # because we dont have hist data for this id
  2             100       2021      2          100 # sum of last month of this product
  3             100       2021      1          0   # etc
  3             100       2021      2          100  # etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to apply the rolling sum per group, you can use `apply` for this:

```
df['Qty_Sum_3qrts'] = (df.groupby('Product_ID')['Quantity']
                         .apply(lambda s: s.shift(1,fill_value=0)
                                           .rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum())
                       )
```

output:

```
   Product_ID  Quantity  Year  Quarter  Qty_Sum_3qrts
0           1       100  2021        1            0.0
1           1       100  2021        2          100.0
2           1        50  2021        3          200.0
3           1       100  2021        4          250.0
4           1       100  2022        1          250.0
5           2       100  2021        1            0.0
6           2       100  2021        2          100.0
7           3       100  2021        1            0.0
8           3       100  2021        2          100.0
```

Comment: Great! I was trying to apply this for the Average as well (replacing .sum() with .mean()). However, that looks not correct for the first two rows (when 3 rows, it is correct). Do you maybe know how to get that one working? I removed min_periods already (without result).

Comment: can you provide the expected output? I would say to remove the `fill_value` as a 0 will be significant for a mean: `df.groupby('Product_ID')['Quantity'].apply(lambda s: s.shift(1).rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean())`